# How to run the update query in JPA

Tags: jpa, sql-update, playframework-2.1

I am playframework application developer. I am using createNativeQuery method in jpa to extracting values from tables through select query. I need to use update query. What i have to do and what will be the return type of that method. Please anyone help me. Thanks in advance..
if i use like this it showing error..

Query query=JPA.em().createNativeQuery("update truck set flag='YES' where shipment_upc=:EAN_code");
        query.setParameter("EAN_code", EAN_code);
        System.out.println(query.getSingleResult());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use createNativeQuery with your update- query and you will get back a Query- Object.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29)

On it use [executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate%28%29) and you get back the number of updated datas.